# How to catch Completer.CompleterError in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing

I would like to know why this test case fails and how can I resolve it.

```
  test('first error  ', () async {
    try {
      final clusterCompleter = Completer<String>();
      clusterCompleter.completeError(Exception("API Error"));
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error: $e");
    }
    print("Passed");
    expect(1, 1);
  });
```

What's confusing is that it prints :

```
Passed

Exception: API Error
```

[image]

Why does it pass and fail at the same time ?

Comment: most likely you need this: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Comment: Your `try`-block needs to do `await clusterCompleter.future;` to catch an asynchronous error thrown by the `Completer`'s `Future`.